# Send PDF in e-mail without saving to phone (android)

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

I'd like to be able to create a PDF from a bytestream/byte array, then send it as an e-mail attachment without requiring it to be stored on the SD card/internal storage of the phone.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/html");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Where `file` is a File object that contains the location of the PDF I'm trying to send.

Is there any way to take the byte array and attach it as a PDF and send it immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to take the byte array and attach it as a PDF and send it immediately?

Only if you write your own email client and embed it in your app.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of ... can I store it in memory?  I'm just wanting to allow them to still e-mail this PDF if they don't have an SD card in, or don't have space on it.

It isn't a requirement, but it'd be nice.

Comment: @kwc2011: "can I store it in memory?" -- that was what you asked in your question and I answered in my answer. "I'm just wanting to allow them to still e-mail this PDF if they don't have an SD card in, or don't have space on it." -- then store it on internal storage. Either create a `ContentProvider` to serve it up and then use its `Uri` for your `Intent`, or save the file using `openFileOutput()` and `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.